# MongoDB - Sort not being applied

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm developing this feature in my Express API in which I have to rate some documents that fit some search parameters. I'm using the map function of a Mongo cursor to generate the field score that represents how much the document match the parameters.

I'm having trouble with the sort of mongoDB in NodeJS. I have this aggregation pipeline and this map function:

```
 const scoreProperty = ({
    document: property,
    score,
  }: {
    document: PropertyType;
    score: number;
  }) => {
    const {
      roomAmount: propRoomAmount,
      developmentProperties,
      propertyType: propPropertyType,
      neighborhood: propNeighborhood,
      tags: propTags,
    } = property;
    const roomAmountEvaluators = roomAmount && roomAmount.map(createEvaluator);
    const roomAmountScore =
      propRoomAmount && roomAmountEvaluators
        ? roomAmountEvaluators.reduce(
            (accumulator, currentValue) =>
              accumulator || currentValue(propRoomAmount),
            false,
          )
          ? 1.5
          : 0
        : 0;
    const roomAmountDevPropScore =
      roomAmountEvaluators && developmentProperties
        ? developmentProperties
            .map(devProp => devProp.roomAmount)
            .map(rma =>
              roomAmountEvaluators.reduce(
                (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator || currentValue(rma),
                false,
              ),
            )
            .some(a => a)
          ? 1.5
          : 0
        : 0;
    const propertyTypeScore =
      propertyType &&
      propertyType.find(propType => propType === propPropertyType)
        ? 1.5
        : 0;
    const neighborhoodScore =
      neighborhood && neighborhood.find(hood => hood === propNeighborhood)
        ? 1.5
        : 0;
    const tagsScore =
      tagsWitouthGarage && tagsWitouthGarage.length
        ? tagsWitouthGarage
            .map(tag =>
              !!propTags && propTags.includes(tag)
                ? (1 as number)
                : (0 as number),
            )
            .reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue) /
          tagsWitouthGarage.length
        : 0;
    const customTagsScore =
      customTagsWithOutAptCredit && customTagsWithOutAptCredit.length
        ? customTagsWithOutAptCredit
            .map(tag =>
              !!propTags && propTags.includes(tag)
                ? (1 as number)
                : (0 as number),
            )
            .reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue) /
          customTagsWithOutAptCredit.length
        : 0;

    return {
      ...property,
      photos: property.photos && property.photos.slice(0, 1),
      score:
        roomAmountScore +
        propertyTypeScore +
        neighborhoodScore +
        tagsScore +
        customTagsScore +
        roomAmountDevPropScore +
        (score ? score : 0),
    };
  };
```

```
    .aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          highlight: { $eq: true },
          ...addressFilter,
        },
      },
      {
        $project: project,
      },
    ])
    .map(scoreProperty)
    .sort({ score: 1 })
    .toArray();
```

It does not matter if I set the sort to -1 or 1 the order is always the same in spite of the value of the score field.

Comment: what are you trying to here : `.map(scoreProperty)` ? Also you need to have `.sort` on aggregation pipeline `.aggregate().sort()`

Comment: I have the .sort, the second piece of code show it. When I do the map I create a score value that represent how well that document fits some requirements.